# How to change the dimensions of the Jssor Image Slider without losing it's responsive nature, image aspect ratio, etc. only on iPhone device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, jssor

The website I'm developing is responsive in nature i.e. the website design gets adjust according to the device on which it is browsed. I've used **Bootstrap framework** for it.

I'm using Jssor JQuery Image slider in my website. It's working fine and perfect for me on all devices and all popular well-known browsers. The only issue I'm facing is when it is viewed on iPhone the size of sliding images in Jssor slider should get changed to dimensions `460 px * 280 px`. In other words, the Jssor image slider should look somewhat bigger than the current size. But while doing this the aspect ratio of the images appearing in slider should be maintained.

Also when the website is viewed on iPhone the image slider should occupy the whole horizontal screen. That is the image slider shouldn't have any white space appearing around the slider. Currently two vertical blank bars are appearing on both sides of the slider.

Initially when the website is viewed on a browser on PC or laptop the resolution of slider images is `940 px * 370 px` and it gets auto adjust as per the size of the device on which it it browsed.

The said dimension change should happen only on iPhone and not on any other devices. On other devices it's working absolutely fine and perfect. Also the aspect ratio of the images should not get disturb in this process.

For your reference I'm putting below the HTML code and jQuery code of the slider. All the necessary library files have been included.

**HTML code :**

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 940px; height: 370px; overflow: hidden; ">

      <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block; background-color: #000000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
      </div>     

      <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 940px; height: 370px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
          <img u="image" src="http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/images/brands/Bud_Light_Lime_1413041685.jpg" />
          <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:350px; bottom: 40px;  width:300px; height:30px;"> 
            slideshow transition twins
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img u="image" src="http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/images/brands/Finlandia_1413041875.jpg" />
          <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:350px; bottom: 40px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
            slideshow transition twins
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img u="image" src="http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/images/brands/Three_Olives_1413042332.jpg" />
          <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute;left:350px; bottom: 40px;  width:300px; height:30px;"> 
            slideshow transition twins
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img u="image" src="http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/images/brands/Avalon_1413041406.jpg" />
          <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:350px; bottom: 40px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
            slideshow transition twins
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img u="image" src="http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/images/brands/Brancott_1413042551.JPG" />
          <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute;left:350px; bottom: 40px;  width:300px; height:30px;"> 
            slideshow transition twins
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>        
      <div u="navigator" class="jssorb05" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; right: 6px;">           
        <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 16px; HEIGHT: 16px;"></div>
      </div>        
      <style>
      .jssorb05 div, .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av {
        background: url(img/b05.png) no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .jssorb05 div {
        background-position: -7px -7px;
      }

      .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av:hover {
        background-position: -37px -7px;
      }

      .jssorb05 .av {
        background-position: -67px -7px;
      }

      .jssorb05 .dn, .jssorb05 .dn:hover {
        background-position: -97px -7px;
      }
      .jssora12l, .jssora12r, .jssora12ldn, .jssora12rdn {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        background: url(img/a12.png) no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .jssora12l {
        background-position: -16px -37px;
      }

      .jssora12r {
        background-position: -75px -37px;
      }

      .jssora12l:hover {
        background-position: -136px -37px;
      }

      .jssora12r:hover {
        background-position: -195px -37px;
      }

      .jssora12ldn {
        background-position: -256px -37px;
      }

      .jssora12rdn {
        background-position: -315px -37px;
      }
      .captionOrange, .captionBlack {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      .captionOrange {
        background: #EB5100;
        background-color: rgba(235, 81, 0, 0.6);
      }
      .captionBlack {
        font-size:16px;
        background: #000;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      }
      a.captionOrange, A.captionOrange:active, A.captionOrange:visited {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      a.captionOrange:hover {
        color: #eb5100;
        text-decoration: underline;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.7);
      }
      .bricon {
        background: url(img/browser-icons.png);
      }
    </style>       
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora12l" style="width: 30px; height: 46px; top: 123px; left: 0px;"></span>
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora12r" style="width: 30px; height: 46px; top: 123px; right: 0px"></span>        
      <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">javascript</a>
    </div>
```

**jQuery code :**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

      var _SlideshowTransitions = [{ $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }];

      var options = {
        $AutoPlay: 1,                                    
        $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  
        $Idle: 3000,                            
        $PauseOnHover: 1,                               
        $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          
        $SlideDuration: 500,                                
        $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          
        $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   
        $Cols: 1,                                  
        $Align: 0,                                
        $UISearchMode: 1,                                   
        $PlayOrientation: 1,                                
        $DragOrientation: 3,                                

        $SlideshowOptions: {                                
          $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 
          $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            
          $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           
          $ShowLink: true                                    
        },

        $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                
          $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       
          $ChanceToShow: 2,                               
          $Steps: 1,                                      
          $Rows: 1,                                      
          $SpacingX: 10,                                   
          $SpacingY: 10,                                   
          $Orientation: 1                                 
        },

        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
          $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              
          $ChanceToShow: 2,                               
          $Steps: 1                                       
        }
      };
      var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

      function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if (parentWidth)
          jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 940));
        else
          window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
          $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
        }       
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I had similar responsivness issues with my custom navigation for some intranet site (using Bootstrap 3) and only thing I have been able to do was after removing position:absolute (and position:fixed). Can you maybe try removing position:absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Your website
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
   //...
   function ScaleSliderDevices() {
             var bodyWidth = DEVICE.Screen.width();
             if (DEVICE.Screen.osDimVariation()) {
                 bodyWidth = DEVICE.Screen.width() + osWidthOffset();
             }
              jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 940));
         };

    //...
    if (DEVICE.mobile())
    {
        $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSliderDevices);
    }

    //as the resize event may not fire at the beginning sometimes, please scale slider manually after document load
    ScaleSliderDevices();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using bootstrap, why not use bootstraps built in carousel? All the responsive work is done for you.

[plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bW5OzNtMejnB80FegDzW)

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/images/brands/Bud_Light_Lime_1413041685.jpg" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                slideshow transition twins
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/images/brands/Three_Olives_1413042332.jpg" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                slideshow transition twins
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/images/brands/Avalon_1413041406.jpg" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                slideshow transition twins
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/images/brands/Brancott_1413042551.JPG" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                slideshow transition twins
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: added resize specific per devices see:

- Added device detection https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js/blob/master/lib/device.js source inside js with small updates made by me to resolve width and height problems on IOS.
- Added Slider Scale to fit body width not parent width, maybe you will need to compute for parent as well width.

  ```
  //Your website
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
  //...
         function ScaleSliderDevices() {
                   var bodyWidth = DEVICE.Screen.width();
                   if (DEVICE.Screen.osDimVariation()) {
                       bodyWidth = DEVICE.Screen.width() + osWidthOffset();
                   }
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 940));
               };

  //...
  if (DEVICE.mobile())
          {
              $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSliderDevices);
          }
  }
  ```
- add resize event for devices (roation mainly)

JSFIDDLE: example does not run on devices use the code in your local website to test it on devices.

http://jsfiddle.net/sp75dzaq/13/

You can find comments there with more details.